# how to make a tmux window remain open after running command

Tags: tmux

I'm fiddling with `tmux`, trying to make it approximate the behavior I've had `screen` set up for to meet my quite modest terminal needs (I'm no programmer).

I just want it to start a couple of Bash sessions, and one instance of Alpine and one of Newsbeuter. I'm most of the way there, the main problem now being invoking a Python program in one of the Bash sessions at start-up.

The problem is that the Bash session wants to close after the Python program starts, whereas I want the Bash session to remain open so as to get STDOUT output from the Python program in that session.

To do that in `screen`, I just put the line:

```
$ screen -t bash1 python2.6 python-prog/prog.py &
```

**NOTE:** along with similar lines for the other 3 terminals I want to open on start-up) in `.screenrc`.

But when I put what seems to me the equivalent in `.tmux.conf`, i.e., `neww -n Bash1 bash python2.6 python-prog/prog.py &`, the Bash session in which the Python program was run, closes.  Meantime, the other 3 terminals start fine under `tmux` and remain open.

So, what am I doing wrong here? How can I run that python program and get the bash session to remain open and displaying STDOUT output?

Comment: `man tmux | less -p remain-on-exit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the command into two lines in your `.tmux.conf`

1. Open the window

   ```
   neww -n Bash1 bash
   ```
2. Send the command to the window

   ```
   send-keys -t "Bash1" 'python2.6 python-prog/prog.py' Enter
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, that did do the trick. I've been searching all day and could not puzzle out on my own how to do this.